# Всем привет, хочу установить Laravel, ввожу в терминал composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app , но после установки возникает ошибка

Tags: php, laravel, backend

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- laravel/framework[v10.10.0, ..., v10.16.1] require league/flysystem ^3.8.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.8.0, ..., 3.15.1]
.
- league/flysystem[3.3.0, ..., 3.14.0] require league/mime-type-detection ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0
, ..., 1.11.0].
- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^10.10 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v10.10.0, ..., v10.16.1].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\php-8.2.8\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Уже разобрался, оказалось нужно было раскомментировать fileinfo в файле C:/php/php.ini